# How to get a div height within owl-carousel on window resize?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I am using owl-Carousel to a project and I need the height of the content div(topSlidetxt) inside owlCarousel on window resize and window load, I have tried this but can't get any positive result yet.

```
$('.heroSlide').owlCarousel({
  smartSpeed: 1500,
  items: 1,
  margin:0,
  nav:true,
  dots:true
});
```

```
<div class="heroSlide owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <div class="topSlideImg">
          <img src="assets/images/home-banner-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5">
        <div class="topSlidetxt">
        <span class="tiTle">South Beach Residences</span>
        <h2>Icon to Many, Home to Few</h2>
        <a class="linkArrow" href="#">DISCOVER MORE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [API Events](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html) ([initialized.owl.carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html#initialized-owl-carousel), [resized.owl.carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html#resized-owl-carousel)) of **Owl Carousel 2**

Example of usage:

```js
$('.heroSlide').owlCarousel({
  smartSpeed: 1500,
  items: 1,
  margin:0,
  nav:true,
  dots:true,
  onInitialized: function () { /* read and use $('.topSlidetxt').height() here */ },
  onResized: function () { /* read and use $('.topSlidetxt').height() here */ },
});
```

live example code: https://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/sna04L7p/